# Warning:PluginListGenerator.php on line 412

Tags: magento2, xampp

I'm getting the error below, when i enter  php C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2.4.5/project-community-edition/bin/magento setup:di:compile

I need help please, the error says the following
*

```
Warning: file_put_contents(C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2.4.5/project-community-edition/generat
  ed/metadata/primary|global|plugin-list.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or direc
  tory in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.4.5\project-community-edition\vendor\magento\framework\I
  nterception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 412
```

- 

Below is the following line in PluginListGenerator.php

```
 private function writeConfig(string $key, array $config)
    {
        $this->initialize();
        $configuration = sprintf('<?php return %s;', var_export($config, true));
        file_put_contents(
            $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::GENERATED_METADATA) . '/' . $key  . '.php',
            $configuration
        );
    }
```

Magento has been installed but i cant access the login page, it says not found...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, got it fixed just needed to replace “|” with “_” in $key variable which contains the file name:

```
 }
     $this->initialize();
     $configuration = sprintf('<?php return %s;', var_export($config, true));
     file_put_contents(
      $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::GENERATED_METADATA) . '/' . str_replace('|', '_', $key)  . '.php',
         $configuration
     );
 }
```

hope it helps anyone who gets stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

To fix above error, kindly follow the below steps

Open **PluginListGenerator.php** file located at **vendor/magento/framework/Interception**.

find the word “**scopePriorityScheme**” in PluginListGenerator.php file

Replace the line

```
$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;
```

with

```
$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;
```

Save the file and run the command

> php bin/magento s:d:com